# Using item's name in the URL address instead of IDs

Tags: php, mysql, url

I have built a PHP-MYSQL website that retrieves products from a database. The items are taken by id in the URL like this: `index.php?id=25`.

However, I just read that this is not the best option for SEO purposes.

Is there any simple way to have the item name and category populated in the URL instead of the id number? Or should I call each item using the field NAME and CATEGORY from the database?

Thanks!

Comment: Aks Google about "mod_rewrite" and you will get thousands of answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `print` the link add some detail to it (that your `index.php` will not use anyway).

So your links will look like: `index.php?id=25&c=Airplanes&q=Fighter+Jet+Z672`

`index.php` will function as before via `id` and ignore `&c=` and `&q=`.

To make this even better you'll use a .htaccess file to rewrite your links to something like: `mysite.com/Airplanes/25-Fighter-Jet-Z672`

Comment: just a question, does the .htaccess need to be stored only in the main directory? Or should it be stored in each directory where I have an index.php?